# Why am I getting this error: migration failed with error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createTable')

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, migration, knex.js

**LOG**

```
npx knex migrate:latest
migration file "20230917031623_createUsers.js" failed
migration failed with error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createTable')
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createTable')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createTable')
    at exports.up (C:\PROJECTS\ENVOLVIDOS_api\src\database\knex\migrations\20230917031623_createUsers.js:1:35)
    at C:\PROJECTS\ENVOLVIDOS_api\node_modules\knex\lib\migrations\migrate\Migrator.js:519:40
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Migrator._runBatch (C:\PROJECTS\ENVOLVIDOS_api\node_modules\knex\lib\migrations\migrate\Migrator.js:381:19)
```

**knexfile.js**

```
`const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    client: 'mysql2',
    connection: {
        database : 'shopbarber',
        user: 'root',
        password: ''
    },
    pool: {
        min: 2,
        max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
        directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "database", "knex", "migrations")
    }
}`
```

**config**

```
`const config = require("../../../knexfile");
const knex = require("knex")(config);

knex.raw("SELECT VERSION()").then(() => {
    console.log('Connection to db succesful')
})

module.exports = knex;`
```

**Migration File**

```
``exports.up = knex => knex.schemas.createTable("users", table => {
    table.increments("id");
    table.string("name", 60).notNullable();
    table.string("telephone", 11).notNullable();
    table.string("email", 90).notNullable().unique();
    table.text("password").notNullable()
    table.string("avatar", 120);
    table.timestamp("created_at").defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamp("updated_at").defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
})`
```

exports.down = knex => knex.schemas.dropTable("users");`

I recreated the migrations, the files, changed functions, I don't know how to resolve it.
The connection is established, I just can't perform the migrations.

Help me?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `knex.schemas` is undefined. The reason for this is because you have a typo, in your `knex.schemas.createTable` the `schemas` should not have an `s`. i.e. change it to `knex.schema.createTable` and it should work.